# Random Positioning issue

Tags: ios, position, game-physics, arc4random

I am trying atm doing a game. I got some problems with the RandomPositioning with the blocks. With my code, the Blocks keep spawning at the same lane very fast. But thats not what I mean to. They should appear like a Mario Game. My Code:

```
HumanMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(HumanMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[self PlaceBlocks];

BlockMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(BlockMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)BlockMoving{

StartingBlock.center = CGPointMake(StartingBlock.center.x -1, StartingBlock.center.y);
Block1.center = CGPointMake(Block1.center.x -1, Block1.center.y);
Block2.center = CGPointMake(Block2.center.x -1, Block2.center.y);

if ( Block1.center.x > 20) {
    [self PlaceBlocks];
}

}

-(void)PlaceBlocks{

    RandomBlock1Position = arc4random() %568;
    RandomBlock1Position = RandomBlock1Position + 140;
    RandomBlock2Position = RandomBlock2Position + 500;

    Block1.center = CGPointMake(193 , RandomBlock1Position);
    Block2.center = CGPointMake(280 , RandomBlock2Position);


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but your RandomBlock2Position seems to never be initialized. I'm not sure that what you want.

Comment: I want the blocks to spawn on the right side, moving to the left while spawning every time the first block reaches x = 170.

Comment: I believe an image would be great to illustrate what you are trying to do. And where do initialize RandomBlock2Position ?

Comment: Simply : There are 2 Blocks, they are 40x40 and they should moving from the right to the left of the screen. They should spawn from the right of the screen and move to the left. And here i got the problem. They only appear on 1 point, moving up and down, and not from the right to the left, while the BeginningBlock is moving from right to left. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Ok, that's clearer. Two more questions though, do you use portrait, landscape or both ? And why do you place block again if center.x >20 ?

Comment: I use only Portrait. I just saw, that if I use the if center.x >20, the issue appear. If I don't use it, the blocks show up, but after they spawned 1 time randomly, they don't spawn again. I want to make the blocks spawn endless.

Comment: So when a block reaches the left side it should respawn, right ?

Comment: shouldn't it be Block1.center.x < 20 instead of Block1.center.x > 20

Comment: There you go. Wow I feel so dumb right now. Thanks for your help and your time Justafinger :)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, i'll be nice for you to accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if i understood correctly your blocks should respawn once the reach the left side. In order to do so you have to change your center check position to :

```
if ( Block1.center.x < 20) {
    [self PlaceBlocks];
}
```